# cost of lines in algorithm help me understand this

Tags: algorithm, analysis, insertion-sort

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBCeD.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aodkF.png

Okay so basically i have an algorithm of an insertion sort, however next to it is a constant which is the cost of running each line of code

now my mathematical background is not very strong but i do understand most of it, however what i cannot make sense of is why is the coefficient of n^2 and n have the constants divided by two?

what is the significance of it? is it because it is a loop within a loop? or maybe because two values are compared? or some other mathematical reason like formula of summation n(n-1)/2

first image is the algorithm in pseudo code and the summation under it the best case scenario(where the algorithm is already sorted) and the second picture is the algorithm worst case scenario(summation) which is where my question is pointed at

note: also tj denote the number of times the while loop test in line 5 is executed for that value of j

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: Can you write the question in a self-contained way? A link to a picture in an external site makes this question less useful than it could be.

Comment: @Adrian i still dont get it?

Comment: @anonymous there is way too much information to write it out without it getting really unreadable and messy

i was originally writing it out but all those elements would have made it really difficult to read and understand, so i put the picture to make it easier to see , its hard to write mathematical notation in this (for equations as long as this)

Comment: Its the closed form solution to the summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a boring night and I wanted to play with latex, so to expand on the comment i left into an actual answer...

To summarize your question.

[image]

Lets start with a basic example.

[image]

Which is equivalent to

[image]

This is where the form comes from. Back to a parameterized sum, we can now see that.

[image]

Note the variable `i` starting at 1. The sum for the algorithm calls for the variable to start at 2. Logically, the sum will be 1 less, so

[image]

To carry it out further... (for one term)
[image]

Comment: hi and thanks for taking the time to answer the question, but maybe i wasnt being clear enough, what i was referring to was the coefficent for n^2 in the second image , as it says (c5/2 + c6/2+ c7/2) and i couldnt understand why the c5, c6 and c7 is being divided? and i was hoping somebody could explain hat i was missing, i do understand summation formula, but i cant see where that fits into it?

Comment: It says (c5/2 + c6/2+ c7/2)n^2 and (c5/2 + c6/2+ c7/2)n.
Multiplication rules. A (B/2) = (A/1) (b/2) = (AB)/2. Then they simply multiplied the coefficient into the numerator and combined like terms.

Comment: wow that is a beautiful explanation , thanks for your time and effort, i didnt realize how imperative the summation formula is in this, thats what i hate about books, they never go into details, they just assume everyone is isaac newtown or albert einstein , if people took teh time to explain what they write, in their books, learning would be so much easier

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help. I agree, I find it very frustrating when the information that is supposed to be teaching you something skips what they consider to be obvious. IMO, at the very least, the first time you introduce something, you shouldn't presume the reader's foreknowledge unless you explicitly state that you do.

Comment: your perfectly correct in that, people lack courteousy, that is the problem, and even if they are the greatest genius in the world but lack courteousy they will fail to share their ideas correctly